# saving image file on Flash without PHP

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is it posible to save a flash scene into an image and save it on client-side hard drive ? Without PHP. I dont care if user has to change flash security options.

Comment: Yes, this is possible.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417740/flash-actionscript-access-filesystem-without-air

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [FileReference](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/FileReference.html)'s [save](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/net/FileReference.html#save%28%29) method to do this.