# How to find references to the file system in a flash application?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, filesystems, action

I need to disable all the aspects of functionality which access the client file system in a flash/flex application. I started having a look on how to do this. It appears that the package flash.filesystem need to be importated to allow the interaction with the file system.

However, I did not find any reference to this package in the application.

I am a beginner concerning these technologies so maybe I am missing a point here. Do I need to look into an other direction?

Thanks

Comment: I don't realy understand your question. What do you want to disable? All the file read/write capabilities of flash?

Comment: @WesleyE - In fact I have the code source of a flash/flex application and I need to disable the functionalities of this application which access the client file system.

Answer (score 2):

Basic flash/as3 resource: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/as3.html

The `flash.filesystem` library is for [AIR applications only](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/filesystem/package-detail.html) because flash is not supposed to be able to reach outside the browser to affect a client's computer. That would be a security violation. Even AIR apps are highly restricted in this way.

Update:

> Related Question:
>
> [flash actionscript access filesystem without air?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417740/flash-actionscript-access-filesystem-without-air)

This is brand-new in Flash 10.

Update 2:

And an older reference in Flash 9 [here](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/SharedObject.html). Though it mentions that it's still subject to the user turning off permissions via their [settings manager](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager03.html).

Comment: OK so if it is not an air application there is no way that this app access the file system?

Comment: @duke: looking a little further, there's some limited access in flash 10. see updated post. but otherwise, yes.

Comment: Actually, you can save data from Flash Player 9 using the SharedObject class:

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/SharedObject.html