# Flash / Flex filesystem limitations?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, filesystems

Is there anything preventing a Flash website from storing several gigs of data using its filesystem / cache? What are the limitations?

Comment: Storing several gigs of data? Elaborate on what the data is and how you're ending up with several gigs of it..?

Comment: Haha. I don't get what you mean by the flash website storing the data?

Comment: I just read another SO post, and apparently each download prompts the user for approval. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417740/flash-actionscript-access-filesystem-without-air

Answer (score 1):

Downloading in Flash is just like downloading anything else, it needs to ask the user where do they want to save it to.

However, for 'saving' several gigs of data means that the data needs to be already on the client side to start with (which you don't want).  I think the better option is to have flash do an http request to the file they want to save and from there the browser takes it over.

Otherwise, if it's streaming data that you want to save, I don't think you can save it to the harddrive directly from Flash. You'll need Air for that.