# Embed Adobe AIR application in html with swfobject

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe, swfobject

I've a .fla program that decompresses ZIP files using BiteArray.
In order to use this BiteArray I change the publish settings of the document in Adobe AIR.

I tried to embed this app in an HTML page as you would for a swf file, so with SWFObject, but nothing is shown, even if I run the swf locally.

There is a particular way to manage an swf in Adobe AIR?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way you can embed an AIR app in a html. AIR is for desktop applications (or mobile).

But you do not need AIR to use `ByteArray` ...

The code you found may use the `File` class. This one is AIR only.

You'll have to work that around.

Comment: +1 And the `FileReference` class might be the specific workaround you need. For security reasons, it means the user has to instigate and specify any save/load operations, as opposed to having the app perform them autonomously. There's a good intro here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/filereference_class_as3.html

Comment: I guess there are a few of uncertainties in my knowledge.
This intro is very helpful!

Comment: Also take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417740/flash-actionscript-access-filesystem-without-air